# How to use uprobe to trace OpenJDK HotSpot source code?

Tags: java-8, java, jvm-hotspot

I try to follow the instructions from [link](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/examples/uprobe_example.txt)

In this [example](https://github.com/brendangregg/perf-tools/blob/master/examples/uprobe_example.txt#L245),

```
Tracing func_abc() in my test program, and including user-level stacks:

# ./uprobe -s p:/root/func_abc:func_c
Tracing uprobe func_c (p:func_c /root/func_abc:0x4f4). Ctrl-C to end.
        func_abc-25394 [000] d... 19603250.054040: func_c: (0x4004f4)
        func_abc-25394 [000] d... 19603250.054056: <user stack trace>
 =>  <00000000004004f4>
 =>  <0000000000400527>
 =>  <0000000000400537>
 =>  <00007fca9f0e376d>
        func_abc-25394 [000] d... 19603251.054250: func_c: (0x4004f4)
        func_abc-25394 [000] d... 19603251.054266: <user stack trace>
 =>  <00000000004004f4>
 =>  <0000000000400527>
 =>  <0000000000400537>
 =>  <00007fca9f0e376d>
^C
Ending tracing...
```

I want to probe function [minor_collection_begin](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/hotspot/file/b756e7a2ec33/src/share/vm/gc/shared/adaptiveSizePolicy.cpp#l223) but it shows `ERROR: missing symbol`.

```
root@wxf:/home/wxf/perf-tool/perf-tools/bin# ./uprobe -s p:/home/wxf/9dev/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/jdk/bin/java:AdaptiveSizePolicy::minor_collection_begin
ERROR: missing symbol "minor_collection_begin" in /home/wxf/9dev/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/jdk/bin/java
root@wxf:/home/wxf/perf-tool/perf-tools/bin# ./uprobe -s p:/home/wxf/9dev/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/jdk/bin/java:minor_collection_begin
ERROR: missing symbol "minor_collection_begin" in /home/wxf/9dev/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/jdk/bin/java
```

I search a lot and find it is related to `libjvm.so`. However, I don't know what to do next.

```
wxf@wxf:/home/wxf/adjustableMaxHeapSize_9jdk_prj/9dev$ find -name "libjvm.so"
./build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/support/modules_libs/java.base/server/libjvm.so
./build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/hotspot/variant-server/libjvm/gtest/libjvm.so
./build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/jdk/lib/server/libjvm.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ symbols are [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) in binary objects. You won't find `minor_collection_begin`. The mangled symbol name for `void AdaptiveSizePolicy::minor_collection_begin()` is

```
_ZN18AdaptiveSizePolicy22minor_collection_beginEv
```